# Laravel-5 Separate model for each log table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I am currently developing an application with `Laravel 5`, my main tables are `users`, `suppliers`, `manufacturers` etc.

Each of these tables has a separate `users_log`,`suppliers_log` log table. The purpose of these log tables is to review operations performed for a single entity (**for example:** logs belonging to a particular manufacturer and the changes made in the past for that manufacturer etc.,)

I am planning to use `Eloquent` and I have generated an `Eloquent` `model` for each of the major tables.

**My Question** : Should I generate separate `Eloquent` models for each of the log tables or just write a method like `user_log()` in the model of the major table to write my log.

**P.S** : Number of users going to use my application are few, therefore writing logs to a database is preferred over file logs.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "right" answer here. The best we can hope for is to find one that fits your situation better than another, but either approach is acceptable. The result will be an opinionated answer, which is generally off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman : I apologise for being unclear. My question should I create new `eloquent model` for `user_log` table or just use the `user` model and write a function to do the logging operation.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins : So I'll just write a method like `saveLog()` and use some `DB::` to write my log because that would be easy for me to perform rather than creating a new eloquent model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would only use a `logs` table, because logs should be something simple/generic/straightforward.

These are the `logs` table columns I would use:

- id
- user_id (User that performed the action we're logging)
- action (description of the action performed: `deleted user`, `updated supplier`, `created manufacturer`, etc)
- url (the URL used to perform the action)
- ip (IP address of the user)
- timestamps

With that in mind, you would then have a standard pivot table for each loggable table type, which in your case would be `log_manufacturer`, `log_supplier` and `log_user` (I'm following the Laravel table naming convention here, but go ahead and use other names if you wish).

This way you can do a global search by any kind of log:

```
$logs = Log::where('user_id', 1)->get(); // get all logs of User 1
```

by specific log type (user, supplier, manufacturer, etc):

```
$logs = Log::has('suppliers')
            ->where('user_id', 1)
            ->get(); // get Supplier logs created by User 1
```

or get all specific models filtered by a `Log`:

```
$manufacturers = Manufacturer::whereHas('logs', function ($query)
{
    $query->where('user_id', 1);
})
->get(); // get all Manufacturers that have been manipulated by User 1
```

In order to create a new entry on the `logs` table, I would then use [Model Observers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers) so that at each `created`, `updated` or `deleted` action it would handle the creation transparently.

Comment: You could also use a [polymorphic relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) between the primary models and the log model.

Comment: Yeah, that could be another approach :)